# How to bind a dropdown list according to another dropdown selected value using ajax in aspnet webforms

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

We have a .aspx page with two HTML SELECT element and we want to load countries in one dropdownlist and load cities of a country in the other.

we are using entity framework to access data.

I tried PageMethods and &Ajax but I could not access my city dropdown from within a static web method. this is what we have so far:

```
<!-- Signup.aspx-->
<select id="cmb_Region" runat="server" onchange="GetCitiesOfRegion();" datatextfield="region_title" datavaluefield="region_id"></select>
<select runat="server" id="cmb_City" datatextfield="city_title" datavaluefield="city_id" class="ui dropdown"></select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetCitiesOfRegion(regionId)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"Signup.aspx/GetCities",
            type:"POST",
            data:'{}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {
                alert("success");
            }
            });
    }
</script>
```

and this is code-behind code:

```
//Signup.aspx.cs
[WebMethod]
    public static List<City> GetCities(int RegionId)
    {
        behbimeh_informationEntities db = new behbimeh_informationEntities();
        return db.City.Where(i => i.region_id == RegionId).ToList();
    }
```

Actually the code is not correct and I dont know how to pass the cmb_region selected value to the webmethod? and I dont know how to bind the cmb_city to the returned List of cities.

please share your knowledge. thanks...

Comment: why use ajax instead of event handler in c#?

Comment: want to be asynchronous post back.

Comment: You will have to load your SELECT client side with javascript. clear it, then load the returned list as list options

Comment: I dont know how to access combobox data source property clientside and also databind method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get cmb_Region value

```
var regionId = $('#<%= cmb_Region.ClientID %>').val();
```

To get cities by region and bind at client side

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetCities(int RegionId)
{
    behbimeh_informationEntities db = new behbimeh_informationEntities();
    var cities=  db.City.Where(i => i.region_id == RegionId).Select(item=>new { item.ValueField, item.TextField }).ToList();
    return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cities);
}
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetCitiesOfRegion(regionId)
{
    $.ajax({
        url:"Signup.aspx/GetCities",
        type:"POST",
        data:'{"RegionId":'+regionId+'}',           
        success: function (r) {
            var cities=JSON.parse(r.d);
            var citiesOptions="";
            for(var i=0;i<cities.length;i++){
                 citiesOptions+='<option value="'+cities[i].Value+'">'+cities[i].Text+'</option>';
            }
            $('#<%= cmb_City.ClientID %>').html(citiesOptions);
        }
        });
}
```

Comment: ok. just change cities[i].Value with value field and cities[i].Text with display value field

Comment: Additional information: Self referencing loop detected with type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.City_185E6273A57031EE5E482C6721B3C6764B3ED66743BE7F37EDD833B7188A1962'. Path '[0].Region.City'.

Comment: regionId passed to web method is always 1

Comment: success function is not fired

Comment: it fires the web method and there is no error, but in the client side nothing happens.

Comment: i have put an alert to show cities[alert(cities)] after json.parse(r), but no messagebox is shown. it seems that success function never executes.

Comment: I mean at browser developer tool that show client side error.

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Comment: i wrote the error, no need to update the answer, thank you though

Comment: ok, one more thing in success function if result "r" return in object then you can try JSON.parse(r.d)

Comment: add a '.d' after r?

Comment: Excellent,  It works like a charm, thank you so much, you really know ajax well.

Comment: yes if it return json object instead of string you can try add '.d' after r

Answer (score 1):

first you will need to clear the existing data, like so:

```
$('#cmb_city').empty();
```

next, you need to load the returned list to your ddl.

```
$.ajax({
        url:"Signup.aspx/GetCities",
        type:"POST",
        data:'{"RegionId":'+$('#cmb_Region').val()+'}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (r) {
               $.each(r, function() { 
                  $('#cmb_city').append($('<option>').text(this.Name).attr('value', this.Id));
               });
            }
        });
```

where **Name** and **Id** are your text and value fields respectively.

you will also probably need to send the selected region.

Comment: the returned object type is an entity type. you sure it will work?

Comment: this.name? this.id? are these predefined or something?

Comment: yes, just change **name** and **id** to your text and value fields respectively

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer like how to bind data from database using Ajax in php

```
<!-- edit.php -->
<?php
include("config.php");
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
echo $id;
$query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM register r
INNER JOIN country c ON r.cuid = c.cuid
INNER JOIN state s ON r.sid = s.sid
INNER JOIN city ct ON r.cid = ct.cid where id='$id'");

while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{

     $fn=$r['firstname'];
     $add=$r['address'];
     $gn=$r['gender'];
     $hobby=$r['hobby'];
     $h=explode(',',$hobby);
     $q=array('reading','traveling','cricket','drawing');
     $country=$r['cuid'];
     $state=$r['sid'];
     $city=$r['cid'];
     echo $gn;
     $edu= $r['education'];
     $email=$r['email'];
     $pass=$r['password'];
     $conpass=$r['conpassword'];
     $phno=$r['phoneno'];
}

?>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#country').on('change',function(){
        var countryID = $(this).val();
        if(countryID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'ajaxData.php',
                data:'cuid='+countryID,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#state').html(html);
                    $('#city').html(html); 
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#state').html(html);
            $('#city').html(html); 
        }
    });

    $('#state').on('change',function(){
        var stateID = $(this).val();
        if(stateID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'ajaxData.php',
                data:'sid='+stateID,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#city').html(html);
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#city').html(html); 
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="update.php">
            <table border="1" align="center">
            <caption>Edit user data</caption>
            <tr>
                <td>First name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fn" value="<?php echo $fn;?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Address</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="add" value="<?php echo $add;?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gender</td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="gn" value="male" <?php echo ($gn=='male')?'checked':'' ; ?> size="17">Male
                <input type="radio" name="gn" value="female" <?php echo ($gn=='female')?'checked':'' ; ?> size="17">Female
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hobby</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value="reading" <?php if(in_array('reading',$h)){echo ("checked:'checked'");}?> >reading
                <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value="traveling" <?php if(in_array('traveling',$h)){echo ("checked:'checked'");}?> >traveling
                <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value="cricket" <?php if(in_array('cricket',$h)){echo ("checked:'checked'");}?> >cricket
                <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value="drawing" <?php if(in_array('drawing',$h)){echo ("checked:'checked'");}?> >drawing</td>
            </tr>
            <?php
            $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM country");

            //Count total number of rows
            $rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($query);
            ?>
            <td>Country</td>
            <td><select name="country" id="country">
                <option value="<?php echo $country;?>"><?php echo $country;?></option>
                <?php
                if($rowCount > 0)
                {
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
                    { 
                        echo '<option value="'.$row['cuid'].'">'.$row['country'].'</option>';
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    echo '<option value="">Country not available</option>';
                }
                ?>
            </select>
            </td></tr>
            <tr>
            <td>State</td>
            <td>
            <select name="state" id="state">
                <option value="<?php echo $state;?>"><?php echo $state;?></option>

            </select>
            </td></tr>
            <tr>
            <td>City</td>
            <td>
            <select name="city" id="city">
                <option value="<?php echo $city;?>"><?php echo $city;?></option>

            </select>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Education</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="edu" value="<?php echo $edu;?>"></td>
            </tr>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="pass" value="<?php echo $pass;?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Confirm password</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="conpass" value="<?php echo $conpass;?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Phone no</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="phno" value="<?php echo $phno;?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id;?>">
                <input type="submit" name="update" value="update"></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>


--------------------

<!--ajaxData.php-->
<?php
//Include database configuration file
include("config.php");

if(isset($_POST["cuid"]) && !empty($_POST["cuid"]))
{
    //Get all state data
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM state WHERE cuid = ".$_POST['cuid']."");

    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    //Display states list
    if($rowCount > 0)
    {
        echo '<option value="">Select state</option>';
        while($row =  mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        { 
            echo '<option value="'.$row['sid'].'">'.$row['state'].'</option>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<option value="">State not available</option>';
    }
}

if(isset($_POST["sid"]) && !empty($_POST["sid"]))
{
    //Get all city data
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM city WHERE sid =".$_POST['sid']."");

    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    //Display cities list
    if($rowCount > 0)
    {
        echo '<option value="">Select city</option>';
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        { 
            echo '<option value="'.$row['cid'].'">'.$row['city'].'</option>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<option value="">City not available</option>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer.